# Drawing tablet only updates two axes at a time

Tags: tablet

I have a Veikk S640 drawing tablet, and one of the problems with it on Linux is that the x-axis doesn't get updated when the pressure-axis gets updated, leading to staggered strokes like [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FHBj.jpg) in Xorg in KDE Plasma. The top stroke is from Gimp, while the bottom stroke is from Krita. This doesn't look like only the x-axis not giving input, but that's what the `xinput test` command says:

```
button press   1 
motion a[0]=4641 a[1]=12079 
motion a[0]=4641 a[1]=12069 a[2]=598 
motion a[0]=4665 a[1]=12047 
motion a[0]=4665 a[1]=12057 a[2]=608 
motion a[0]=4678 a[1]=11987 
motion a[0]=4678 a[1]=12018 a[2]=614 
motion a[0]=4695 a[1]=11984 
motion a[0]=4695 a[1]=11999 a[2]=621 
motion a[0]=4710 a[1]=11922 
motion a[0]=4710 a[1]=11956 a[2]=562 
motion a[0]=4719 a[1]=11909 
motion a[0]=4719 a[1]=11930 a[2]=419 
motion a[1]=11834 
motion a[1]=11876 a[2]=268 
motion a[1]=11826 
motion a[1]=11848 a[2]=0 
button release 1
```

The y-axis(`a[1]`) gets updated every step, while every time the pressure-axis(`a[2]`) is updated it seems to cause the x-axis(`a[0]`) to not update.

This seems to only be a problem in Xorg, but I can't switch to Wayland as the pressure doesn't work in any program there.

This is specifically a problem in the KDE Neon distribution. I tried several different distributions, even some with up to date KDE Plasma such as Kubuntu, and had no problems. I wasn't able to track down if there was a specific package in KDE Neon causing this. I've moved onto Kubuntu as a workaround now since it works, but can't provide a fix.

Comment: Welcome to [unix.se]!  **:-)** Does that mean that [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/513970/how-to-set-separate-x-and-y-deceleration-in-xinput) is no longer relevant and you have a solution to that?

Comment: @Fabby unfortunately no.